# Python tkinter code - frames with imported image buttons

Tags: python, tkinter

Currently the program opens up an empty blank window when trying to import images as buttons. Without trying to import the image as buttons, the code works fine however. Can anyone help fix this code up or point me in the right direction?

```
from tkinter import*
root = Tk()

class app(Tk):

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    container = Frame(self)

    container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand = True)

    container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
    container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

    self.frames = {}

    for F in (StartPage, SignIn, SignUp):

        frame = F(container, self)

        self.frames[F] = frame

        frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

    self.show_frame(StartPage)

def show_frame(self, cont):

    frame = self.frames[cont]
    frame.tkraise()


class StartPage(Frame):

def __init__(self, parent, controller):
    Frame.__init__(self, parent)
    label = Label(self, text="Start Page")
    label.pack(pady=10,padx=10)

    img1 = PhotoImage(file="signinbtn.png")
    button = Button(self, image=img1,
                        command=lambda: controller.show_frame(SignIn))
    button.pack()

    img2 = PhotoImage(file="signupbtn.png")
    button2 = Button(self, image=img2, text="Sign Up",
                        command=lambda: controller.show_frame(SignUp))
    button2.pack()


class SignIn(Frame):

def __init__(self, parent, controller):
    Frame.__init__(self, parent)
    label = Label(self, text="Sign In")
    label.pack(pady=10,padx=10)

    button1 = Button(self, text="Back to Start Page",
                        command=lambda: controller.show_frame(StartPage))
    button1.pack()



class SignUp(Frame):

def __init__(self, parent, controller):
    Frame.__init__(self, parent)
    label = Label(self, text="Sign Up")
    label.pack(pady=10,padx=10)

    button1 = Button(self, text="Back to Start Page",
                        command=lambda: controller.show_frame(StartPage))
    button1.pack()



   root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Same as every other Tkinter image problem question on this site: you are referring to your images via local variables only, so they get garbage-collected before they can ever be seen.  Use `self.img1` instead of `img1`, perhaps.

Answer (score 0):

The empty window is created by the second code line:

```
root = Tk()
```

Apart from this line you have just class definitions. As you never instantiate any of the classes no code from any class is run.